# F# - Can I use type name as a function which acts as the default constructor?

Tags: f#

To create a sequence of my class,

```
type MyInt(i:int) =
    member this.i = i

[1;2;3] |> Seq.map(fun x->MyInt(x))
```

where `fun x->MyInt(x)` seems to be redundant. It would be better if I can write `Seq.map(MyInt)`

But I cannot. One workaround I can think of is to define a separate function

```
let myint x = MyInt(x)
[1;2;3] |> Seq.map(myint)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, no.

Object constructors aren't first-class functions in F#. This is one more reason to not use classes, discriminated unions is better to use here:

```
type myInt = MyInt of int
let xs = [1;2;3] |> Seq.map MyInt
```

If you don't like explicit lambdas, sequence expression looks nicer in your example:

```
let xs = seq { for x in [1;2;3] -> MyInt x }
```

Alternatively, your workaround is a nice solution.

Answer (score 9):

If gratuitous hacks don't bother you, you could do:

```
///functionize constructor taking one arg
let inline New< ^T, ^U when ^T : (static member ``.ctor`` : ^U -> ^T)> arg =
  (^T : (static member ``.ctor`` : ^U -> ^T) arg)

type MyInt(i: int) =
  member x.i = i

[0..9] |> List.map New<MyInt, _>
```

EDIT: As kvb pointed out, a simpler (and less hacky) signature can be used:

```
let inline New x = (^t : (new : ^u -> ^t) x)
```

Note, this switches the type args around, so it becomes `New<_, MyInt>`.

Comment: Your definition of `New` doesn't compile for me in the VS11 Beta.  However, a simpler variant does: `let inline New x = (^t : (new : ^u -> ^t) x)`.

Comment: I tried that first, but with explicit constraints `^t when ^t : (new :  ^u -> ^t)` which doesn't compile in VS2010. Glad to know there's a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Oddly the compiler only supports explicit constructor constraints of the form `new : unit -> 't` (which are directly representable in .NET metadata), but you can apparently use more general constructor constraint _invocation expressions_ and let the compiler infer the constraints.  It's definitely a bit of a hole in the system.

Answer (score 1):

To give an update on this - [F# 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2014/11/12/announcing-a-preview-of-f-4-0-and-the-visual-f-tools-in-vs-2015.aspx) has upgraded constructors to first-class functions, so they can now be used anywhere a function or method can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I use static methods for this purpose. The reason is that sometimes your object constructor needs two arguments taken from different sources, and my approach allows you to use `List.map2`:

```
type NumRange(value, range) =
    static member Make aValue aRange = new NumRange(aValue, aRange)

let result1 = List.map2 NumRange.Make values ranges
```

Partial application is not prohibited as well:

```
let result2 =
    values
    |> List.map NumRange.Make
    |> List.map2 id <| ranges
```

If you dislike using `id` here, you may use `(fun x y -> x y)` which is more readable.